# Joining to the same table with different filters

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera

I am trying to count, for each `id`, the number of distinct `app` downloaded by the user, grouping the count by category. An example of the separate queries are as such:

```
SELECT id
,COUNT(DISTINCT app) AS gaming_apps
FROM apps_table 
WHERE app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG') 
GROUP BY id 

SELECT id 
,COUNT(DISTINCT app) AS msg_apps
FROM apps_table 
WHERE app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger') 
GROUP BY id 

SELECT id 
,COUNT(DISTINCT app) AS fin_apps
FROM apps_table 
WHERE app IN ('Yahoo Finance', 'Robinhood') 
GROUP BY id
```

Ideally, I would want to return a table with the columns `id` `gaming_apps` `msg_apps` `fin_apps`. I thought about `LEFT JOIN` the 3 queries together but I am not sure how, and wrapping each as a subquery would be too unwieldy.

I also tried this, to no avail because a new row is inserted per download or app update:

```
SELECT id
,COUNT(CASE WHEN app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS gaming_apps
,COUNT(CASE WHEN app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger')  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS msg_apps
,COUNT(CASE WHEN app IN ('Yahoo Finance', 'Robinhood') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS fin_apps 
FROM apps_table 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Check out COUNT_IF

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct counts, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG') THEN app END) AS gaming_apps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger') THEN app END) AS msg_apps,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN app IN ('Yahoo Finance', 'Robinhood') THEN app END) AS fin_apps 
FROM apps_table 
GROUP BY id ;
```

Note that `ELSE NULL` is redundant, because `NULL` is the default value if there are no matches in the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you can use SUM instead of count in your query.

```
SELECT id
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gaming_apps
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS msg_apps
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Yahoo Finance', 'Robinhood') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fin_apps 
FROM apps_table 
GROUP BY id
```

I think this should work. if it doesnt work then, like you said do a left join.

```
SELECT main.id as id,
gaming_apps,
msg_apps, 
...

FROM apps_table  main
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id,COUNT(DISTINCT app) AS gaming_apps FROM apps_table  WHERE app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG')  GROUP BY id) gaming_apps ON gaming_apps .id=main.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id ,COUNT(DISTINCT app) AS msg_apps FROM apps_table  WHERE app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger')  GROUP BY id) msg_apps ON msg_apps.id=main.id 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that adding `OVER (PARTITION BY id)` also works in counting only distinct records (not sure why?), albeit returning duplicate rows of the same values depending on how many `app` entries each `id` has in the table. Without `OVER (PARTITION BY id)`, it will simply count the matches without consideration of distinct values, inflating the number if the `id` has multiple entries of the same `app`.

```
SELECT id
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Clash of Clans', 'Valorant', 'PUBG') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS gaming_apps
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Telegram', 'WhatsApp', 'Signal', 'FBMessenger')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS msg_apps
,SUM(CASE WHEN app IN ('Yahoo Finance', 'Robinhood') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS fin_apps 
FROM apps_table 
GROUP BY app, id
```

To remove the duplicates, I then wrap the results as a subquery and `SELECT DISTINCT` or using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id)` to create a ranking to then filter with.